# Переменную по строчно записать в массив

Tags: php

Всем привет

имеем:

```
<textarea name=\"textarea_2\"></textarea>
```

Допустим человек сюда что либо записал, далее мы это передаем форме, которая записывает это в таблицу. Можно ли как то сделать, что бы все, что передалось, преобразовывалось в массив? Да, сразу можно подумать о том, что мне нужно создать несколько инпутов, и уже так разбирать что к чему (что логично), но если бы это было так, я бы это не спросил.

обычно на входе может быть такое (без знаков //) :

```
//маша
//катя
//оля
//юля
```

собственно когда передаем это все, я получаю переменную $textarea_2, вот из нее охота сделать массив ($textarea_2_arr) , в котором будет содержимое, что то в роде:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>
    [1] => маша
    [2] => катя
    [3] => оля
    [4] => юля
)
```

первый элемент массива у меня всегда пустой, остальное - построчно разбитая переменная $textarea_2. Подскажите как ее так разбить?

Comment: Некто тырит записи)

Comment: 11111111111111111111111

Comment: не догнал, о чем речь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй

```
explode("\r\n",$textarea_2);
```

- `\r\n` - только в винде,
- `\n` - юникс,
- `\r` - мак.

Answer (score 1):

```
explode("\n",$textarea_2);
```

Comment: элемент массива получился: машакатяоляюля